# Division, Remainders and only Real Numbers Allowed

Tags: math, division

Trying to figure out this pseudo code. The following is assumed....
I can only use unsigned and signed integers (or long).
Division returns a real number with no remainder.
MOD returns a real number.
Fractions and decimals are not handled.

```
INT I = 41828;
INT C = 15;
INT D = 0;

D = (I / 65535) * C;
```

How would you handle a fraction (or decimal value) in this situation?  Is there a way to use negative value to represent the remainder?

In this example I/65535 should be 0.638, however, with the limitations, I get 0 with a MOD of 638.  How can I then multiply by C to get the correct answer?

Hope that makes sense.

MOD here would actually return 23707, not 638.  (I hope I'm right on that :) )

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What is MOD?

Comment: MOD returns the remainder.  So, say I had 6/4 DIV would return 1 and MOD would return 2.  I need to edit my answer above...638 is not correct for MOD.  :)  Just saw that.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to switch your order of operations on that last line, you would get the integer answer you're looking for (9, if my calculations are correct)

```
D = (I * C) / 65535
/* D == 9 */
```

Is that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: I think that might work for my purposes.  If anyone does have an answer about how to handle decimals in a situation like I described, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: I posted a proposed mechanism to handle decimals.  It's really ugly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are the values you're always using for this computation, then I would do something like:

```
 D = I / (65535 / C);
```

or

```
 D = I / 4369;
```

Since C is a factor of 65535.  This will help to reduce the possibility of overruning the available range of integers (i.e. if you've only got 16 bit unsigned ints).

In the more general case you, if you think there's a risk that the multiplication of I and C will result in a value outside the allowed range of the integer type you're using (even if the final result will be inside that range) you can factor out the [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) of the numerator and denominator as in:

```
INT I = 41828; 
INT C = 15; 
INT DEN = 65535;

INT GCDI = GCD(I, DEN);
DEN = DEN / GCDI;
I = I / GCDI;

INT GCDC = GCD(C, DEN);
DEN = DEN / GCDC;
C = C / GCDC;

INT D = (I * C) / DEN;
```

Where DEN is your denominator (65535 in this case).  This will not provide you with the correct answer in all cases, especially if I and C are both mutually prime to DEN and I*C > MAX_INT.

As to the larger question you raise, division of integer values will always loose the decimal component (equivalent to the floor function).  The only way to preserve the information contained in what we think of as the "decimal" part is through the remainder which can be derived from the modulus.  I highly encourage you to not mix the meanings of these different number systems.  Integers are just that integers.  If you need them to be floating point numbers, you should really be using floats, not ints.  If all you're interested in doing is displaying the decimal part to the user (i.e. you're not really using it for further computation) then you could write a routine to convert the remainder into a character string representing the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to handle decimals is this replacement division function.  There are numerous obvious downsides to this technique.

```
ALT DIV (dividend, divisor) returns (decimal, point)
for point = 0 to 99
  if dividend mod divisor = 0 return dividend / divisor, point
  dividend = divident * 10
return dividend / divisor, 100
```